# Is there a comprehensive list of capsule hotels or an easy way to find them?

Tags: online-resources, hotels

I've never been in a capsule hotel, but these seem an affordable and interesting solution.

Is there a resource on line that lists capsule hotels around the world?
Or, is there an easy way to find capsule hotels?

Answer (score 1):

A [Google search for capsule hotels worldwide](https://www.google.com/search?q=capsule%20hotels%20worldwide&rlz=1CAACAV_enUS755US755&oq=capsule%20hotels%20worldwide&aqs=chrome..69i57.5683j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns dozens of resources, starting with Booking.com that has [341 capsule hotels available.](https://www.booking.com/capsule-hotel/index.html)